# Rails: Active Record prevents me from using my model in controller:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've just start to creating new app from scratch and call a Pocket model from this controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController  
  def index
  end

  def wallets_index
  end

  def wallets_show
  end

  def wallets_new
    @pocket = Pocket.new
  end
end
```

and this odd error appeared:

> transaction is defined by Active Record. Check to make sure that you don't have an attribute or method with the same name.

my schema:

```
  create_table "pockets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "address"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "transaction"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_pockets_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "pockets", "users"
```

And Pocket model:

```
class Pocket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is actually the first time that happened to me and I have no idea which attribute should I rename in order to avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `transaction` column in your `Pocket` model

```
t.integer "transaction"
```

I would suggest against using a column which has a similar name to a rails method. The `transaction` method is defined in [transcations.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1f29b2dd5c634a6953a636ce1b01b7a4c3a0a89f/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb) module of `Rails`

But, if you really want to use it, you can check [safe_attributes gem](https://github.com/bjones/safe_attributes).

Answer (score 1):

In your `pockets` table or migration, 
 `transaction` is a reserved word, so you cannot use that word.